# Normalising data to [-1 and 1] , but 0 value needs to be preserved

Tags: python, normalization

I have a range of r=data which is both positive and negative. I wanted to normalize it to the [-1,1] range.

I used
`apply(lambda x: -1 + (2*((x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min()))))`
which normalised the data from -1 to 1, but in my data 0 is significant and thus I would like to needs to be preserved it.

How can I accomplish it ?

Comment: This sounds like you really have a math question rather than a programming question. The problem is to *design* the rule that tells you what the result value should be for a given input, not to implement it.

Comment: Could normalize separately [x.min, 0] and [0, xmax] (when xmin < 0 < xmax) an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using numpy you can do this

Input:

`r =(-5,-10,0,1,17)`

```
import numpy as np
normalized = np.where(r>0,r/r.max(),np.where(r<0,-r/r.min(),r))
```

Output:

`normalized = (-0.5 ,-1 ,0 ,0.0588235,1 )`

I think that you are expecting this kind of result

Comment: Thank you ! Yes this is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I have data in different columns. How can I use the np.apply with this rule so that it applies separately to all the column ?

Comment: can you please able to share a structure of the column.i think you need to do the same think for different column correct or otherwise your data structure is in (1,M) structure.

Comment: This is what I had done previously normalised = data[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(lambda x: -1 + (2*((x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())))). and all the colouns got normalised by this rule. However when I do normalised = data[['A', 'B', 'C']].apply(np.where(data>0,data/data.max(),np.where(data<0,-data/data.min(),data))) I get 
ValueError: no results

Comment: I have three columns with 1987 rows.

Comment: just loop through every column and and it as a new column then perform the action

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is taking your `min` and `max` and assuming that this is range that you work within. Then you squeeze all values **and shift** them so that they fit into [-1, 1] range.

The problem is: when extremums are on a different distance from 0, you will have to shift and that will shift all zeros. This is correct mathematically as it preserves distribution.

Say, for sequence `[-1, 0, 2]` extremums are `-1` and `2`. After manipulations, it will become `[-1, -0.66, 1]`.

To fight this, you have to assume that the range you work within is at equal distance from zero on both sides. So that would be your max extremum. In the example above that is `2`. Now if you assume that you work within `[-2, 2]` range, your sequence will become `[-0.5, 0, 1]`.

This is easily achieved simply by dividing all of the items by max extremum.

```
def normalize(seq):
    extremum = max(abs(i) for i in seq)
    return [i / extremum for i in seq]
```